# DLLX file missing in bin folder

Tags: asp.net, .net, sitecore, .net-assembly

I am setting up a sitecore website. It is working fine at out client and they have sent me the zip of the whole website folder and I am trying to setup on my dev server.

I am getting this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'custom.dllx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

They have a custom developed custom.dll file in the bin folder but I don't know what is dllx file, they never developed a dllx file.

Can anybody help how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Sounds like a bad reference somewhere in config or msbuild file. Do a lexical search

Comment: any help please?

Comment: I second what Aluan has said. Sounds like some file is referencing the `.dllx` extension. I would do a full search on the Website folder (I use Agent Ransack) for `custom.dllx` or just `dllx` and see what happens.